# How to show "ALL" for all multiselect input controls in Ireport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a report where I have three mutliselect input controls, and i want to show all input values at the bottom of the reports, to do this I added the text field with condition like this :-

```
      $P{p_project_location}==null ? "All" : $P{p_project_location}
      $P{p_project_manager}==null ? "All" : $P{p_project_manager}
      $P{p_project_phase}==null ? "All" : $P{p_project_phase}
```

If I run the report first time without choosing any parameter values, it shows "All" for all three input controls but once i select any of the input control others don't show "All".

```
      project_location = [India]
      project_manager  = []
      project_phase    = []
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the isEmpty possiblity as well:

```
 $P{p_project_location} == null? " 'All' " :
     ($P{p_project_location}.isEmpty() ? " 'All' ":
         $P{p_project_location}
     )
```

Comment: I have one more question, All the input controls values are closed by these [] like [India], how can i remove these?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can, since this is a collection parameter. I haven't tested this, but try: $P{p_project_location.replace("[", "")

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
    $P{p_project_location}.isEmpty() ? " 'All' ": $P{p_project_location}
```